# Run script exactly after log-in from suspend

Tags: scripting, systemd, suspend, elementary-os

Running on Ubuntu 18.04 -> elementary OS 5.1 I was searching for a way to run a small shell script after I log-in from suspend. The script itself is a one liner. Basically restarting the software I use for Multitouch gestures.

Libinput-gesture-setup restart

So what I found was to create an executable file in /lib/systemd/system-sleep.

Problem is that this is being run to early for my needs. Libinput-gesture seems to load only after I "logged in" again. I need the script to load after that point.

Do you know a way to enable that? Thanks very much

I typed this on my phone... So there might be some errors

Comment: Your desktop manager likely has "Notifications" which can be used to make sounds, display messages, or run scripts. "Screen unlocked" is likely one of these notifications (at least on the KDE desktop).

Answer (score 0):

As it turned out. This was the wrong approach. 
My problem had more to do with a detachable keyboard. I know try to make it work by a udev rule when connecting the keyboard.

This Issue may be closed